# AS3 fullScreenSourceRect is pixelating vectors

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm currently developing a Flash website that incorporates an flv player. The controls on the player's skin are all vectors.

I've set it up so that when you hit fullscreen on the player controls a fullScreenSourceRect  is created which is working great.

However when the the player is full screen, the once crisp vectors are now pixelated as if they were a bitmap.

I'm hoping I'm just missing a property somewhere that scales the vectors properly.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

set `video.smoothing = true;`

Comment: Thanks daidai, I tried applying smoothing to the movieclips for each video control icon but it didn't improve anything.

Comment: you should add the smoothing to the video object. it should look similiar to 'var video:Video = new Video(); video.smoothing = true;
            video.attachNetStream(stream);
            stream.play(videoURL);
            addChild(video);
'. can you post some of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Flash often creates bitmap of display objects for faster rendering. You may have to check the cacheAsBitmap property on some of the components and make sure it's set to false when the stage is full screen.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, I've checked the cacheAsBitmap on the overall player, the control bar and each individual icon. All of which were false.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by rebuilding the fullscreen code so the video player get's set to stage height and width rather than zooming a rectangle.